# Display registration errors in WordPress without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

My aim is to display registration errors in WordPress without a page reload. I'm currently hooking a custom function to `registration_errors`. My custom function checks for errors in the sign up form and adds an error when one occurs. For example:

```
function myplugin_check_fields( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {

    $errors->add( 'demo_error', __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: This is a demo error. Registration halted.','mydomain') );

    return $errors;

}

add_filter('registration_errors', 'myplugin_check_fields', 10, 3);
```

The error added by my custom function displays on screen after the registration page has been reloaded. How can I ensure that registration errors display on screen without a page reload?

Comment: Validate the form on the client with javascript. Or what kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: Problem is I want to avoid a page reload at all costs. What happens if my client side validation misses something validated server side or the user has JS disabled. A page reload will result

Comment: If the user has JS disabled then the page will ALWAYS reload when posting a form, or clicking a link etc. Thats how the web works.

Comment: If you want to pre-validate on the server side you can use AJAX to post the form to server and have it send back any errors.

Comment: I think pre validating server side then responding via JS is the way to go. How can I make sure my PHP processing function emulates all checks done by WordPress? will I have to rewrite the validation done by WordPress or can I reuse it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/registration_errors) you can hook into `registration_errors`.

> The `registration_errors` filter hook is used to create custom
>   validation rules on user registration. This fires when the form is
>   submitted but before user information is saved to the database.

Provided that you add a `validate-only`field to the form data:

```
// this is just a general concept, not working code
function myplugin_check_fields( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
    // AJAX check
    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
        if isset($_POST['validate-only')) {
            echo json_encode ( $errors );
            wp_exit();
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'myplugin_check_fields', 10, 3 );
```

Although its not that great since the only way I know of to halt wordpress from continuing to output an "error form" is `wp_exit` (Which is [`exit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) in disguise, *should* only be used if there is an irrecoverable error).

In the long run you may be better off writing your own validation script to pre-post to.

Comment: Thanks for this. What's the purpose of the validate only field?

Comment: To indicate that you only want to validate the form. It basically gives you a sure fire hook to stop the execution before the user data is saved to the database. Which you should only do when the user clicks the submit button (for ethical and legal reasons).

Comment: But I do want the form to submit but only if there has been no registration errors.

Comment: Then you post it via ajax and remove the validate-only field. What I´m saying is that you should bind it to the form submit event, not key-press, change or whatever.

Comment: Yep I will but what I really need is a sure fire way of stopping form submission if there is a registration error either from my own custom validation or the standard validation checks performed by Wordpress

Comment: Add your errors to to the $errors array and check the length at the end of your custom validation hook. Anything more than 0 should be invalid.

Comment: Will that take into account any errors WordPress has found or just the errors my own function has found?

Comment: The Codex article points to wp-login.php as the source file for the registration_errors hook. Actually, I'm not so sure that is the source file for that hook